# Table of objects - uniq

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have a following table:

```
[ 
   { somename1: 
       { 
         field1: 'field1',
         field2: 'field2',
         field3: [Object]
       } 
   },
   { somename2: 
       { 
         field1: 'field1',
         field2: 'field2',
         field3: [Object]
       }
    },
    { somename1: 
       { 
         field1: 'field1',
         field2: 'field2',
         field3: [Object]
       } 
   } 
]
```

What I would like to obtain is:

```
[
   { somename1: 
     { 
       field1: 'field1',
       field2: 'field2',
       field3: [Object]
     } 
   },
   { somename2: 
     { 
       field1: 'field1',
       field2: 'field2',
       field3: [Object]
     }
   }
]
```

I've tried with `_.uniq(table)` and underscore in general, but I have failed. Do you know what should I do?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Youve seen the extra parameter (`iteratee`) on `uniq`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using underscore:

```
var result = _.uniq(data, function(item){
    return _.first( _.keys(item));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easy without underscore:

```
var o = [ { somename1: 
     { field1: 'field1',
       field2: 'field2',
       field3: [Object]
     } 
   },
   { somename2: 
     { field1: 'field1',
       field2: 'field2',
       field3: [Object]
     }
   },
   { somename1: 
     { field1: 'field1',
       field2: 'field2',
       field3: [Object]
     } 
} ];

var tmp = [], res = [];
o.forEach(function(a, i) {
    var key = Object.keys(a)[0];
    if (tmp.indexOf(key) < 0) {
        tmp.push(key);
        res.push(o[i]);
    }
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you :) I've used the solution with underscore :)